# OSX Jenkins Slave terminates with java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel despite running "headless"

Tags: macos, ssh, jenkins

We are running Jenkins master on Win machine and added Mac OSX slave, exectued via ssh on remote Mac. It's already well known that this scenario requires the slave command being launched with `java -Djava.awt.headless=true` or the connection will be terminated with `java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel`. Despite that, we still experience this exception. Strange is, that the exception is not thrown after constant period of time - in one build, it's e.g. 30 minutes, in another 45 minutes.
What could be wrong?

Attaching log (IPs and URLs additionally mangled)

```
[11/14/13 16:08:11] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to our.macos.machine:22.
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] Authentication successful.
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] The remote users environment is:
BASH=/bin/bash
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING=set
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="48" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-apple-darwin12")
BASH_VERSION='3.2.48(1)-release'
DIRSTACK=()
EUID=503
GROUPS=()
HOME=/Users/hudson
HOSTNAME=our.macos.machine
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
IFS=$' \t\n'
LOGNAME=hudson
MACHTYPE=x86_64-apple-darwin12
MAIL=/var/mail/hudson
OPTERR=1
OPTIND=1
OSTYPE=darwin12
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PPID=93411
PS4='+ '
PWD=/Users/hudson
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 49852 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 49852 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy 22'
TERM=dumb
TMPDIR=/var/folders/hg/298vj1kd4yj_f73tgbh6n0hr0000gq/T/
UID=503
USER=hudson
_=bash
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] Checking java version of java
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] java -version returned 1.7.0_40.
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] Copied 346 309 bytes.
Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
[11/14/13 16:08:12] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd '/Users/hudson/build' && java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar slave.jar
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Slave.jar version: 2.32
This is a Unix slave
Evacuated stdout
Slave successfully connected and online
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and found the resolution here: http://blog.narf.ssji.net/2012/11/fix_jenkins_unexpected_channel_termination

In short, I added the line below under Node Setup > Launch Method > Advanced JVM Options:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope. I already mentioned this in the question description, as not helpful.